# pdo_oci driver not found but is listed in available drivers

Tags: php, pdo, oracle11g, oracle-call-interface

I am trying to connect to an Oracle Database 11g XE running on windows from a remote Ubuntu 14.04 server using PDO_OCI in php. I followed this guide http://gist.github.com/tassoevan/10392954 (numerous times) and keep getting the following error:

> could not find driver

However when I call PDO::getAvailableDrivers() it gives me this:

> Array ( [0] => mysql [1] => oci [2] => sqlite )

Note: oci wasn't there before I followed the guide in the link above.

All of the other tutorials I could find were basically the same thing.

I have the Oracle instant client installed (version 11.1). The latest version was not even getting the driver to show up in the list of available drivers.

Also I know that the driver which is used in this method is older but there are no step by step guides on how to get it working with the lastest one. I am new to Oracle Databases as well as php so step by step help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
I figured out the driver problem. It was in my php code, and something very silly. I am posting for the benefit of others.

My original code had "OCI" in capital letters when setting the connection.

```
$tns = "  
(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myIP)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
       ";

try{
$pdo = new PDO('OCI:dbname='.$tns ,'username','password'); // Capital 'OCI' here is WRONG so changed to 'oci:dbname='
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());
```

However, I am having problems querying the Database. It seems nothing is happening. I have allowed the port 1521 in the Windows firewall for both incoming and outgoing. Any suggestion?

Here is my php code:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `PDO`;");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchColumn(0);
echo $result;
```

The table `PDO` only has one column with one row.

Does the Oracle database need to be configured to allow for remote connections?

Comment: Show us your code where you try to connect to the database and set up PDO.

Comment: Thanks Brad, your request caused me to look closer at the code. I 'solved' the driver error but now I don't know why it's not querying the database. See above.

Comment: PDO unfortunately doesn't throw exceptions by default.  Use `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` and see if your `try`/`catch` block gets fired.

Comment: Nothing changes after adding setAttribute(). I added some echo statements before and after the pdo query and the one After the query never comes up. So I'm thinking it might be in the query itself or its execution?

Comment: Try a `var_dump($e);`... some Exceptions don't have messages (but that's rare).  More likely, there is some useful information in your PHP error log.

Comment: Thanks Brad! Your help was awesome. The var_dump() gave me an error 'General error: 911 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-00911: invalid character' which I guessed was the quotes surrounding `PDO` in the query. And removing them fixed it. I guess Oracle doesn't like that because it works in MySQL. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: No problem, and good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two problems with my PHP code. 
1) The way the PDO connection was initiated was incorrect ... see update in original post. That solved my driver problem.

2) Oracle doesn't seem to like the backtick character, unlike MySQL. So I had to remove them from my query to look like this

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM PDO"); // Originally was SELECT * FROM `PDO`
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchColumn(0);
echo $result;
```

This solved my database querying problem.